# New Tab using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I open a new tab using `Selenium` WebDriver all the other answers I found were out of date and/or inaccurate.

I've tried:

```
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

but this does not work reliably and needs manual switching to the new tab that's unreliable

Comment: Look into driver handles it's actually not that hard to switch tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your send_keys method to open a new tab, and I believe Selenium also offers a function to switch tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so Finally I found a foolproof solution to this problem the solution is actually there in the official Selenium website but this worked perfectly for me

- Update selenium to its alpha version using
  `pip install selenium==4.0.0.a7`

[Link to downloads page on official selenium website](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

Yeah and then you can create a new tab using this command:

[Link to Selenium Documentation on it's offical website](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/)

```
# Opens a new tab and switches to new tab
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')

# Opens a new window and switches to new window
driver.switch_to.new_window('window')
```